# Are the tigers at Tiger Kingdom in Phuket drugged?

Tags: zoology

The [Tiger Kingdom](http://www.tigerkingdom.com/Phuket.html) attraction in Phuket lets you walk into the enclosure and pose for photos with real, live, full-size tigers.

[Man literally about to get eaten by tiger. http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/phuket-com/homepage/phuket-magazine/tiger-kingdom/allParagraphs/0/image/tiger-kingdom-phuket.jpg](http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/phuket-com/homepage/phuket-magazine/tiger-kingdom/allParagraphs/0/image/tiger-kingdom-phuket.jpg)

They claim that the tigers are not drugged. From their website:

> Tigers at Tiger Kingdom are hand raised by their trainers since young, bonding with it throughout the development process. The trainer employ a combination of repetition, trust and encouragement to train their big cats and over time the Big Cat are use to human and often see us as one of the family.

I call shenanigans. How is it possible to get close to a tiger and have it not attack/eat you? Is it possible they are lying about drugging the tigers? Would it be possible to keep the tigers extremely well fed and reduce their appetite for attack?

Comment: I probably need help phrasing the question, but the gist is that I believe Tiger Kingdom is doing something shady with the tigers, or humans are actually at risk, while the company claims everything is above board.

Comment: There are multiple people who own tiger as a pet. https://www.google.com.au/#q=tiger+as+a+pet I don't see anything too unbelievable in the fact that they don't just attack everyone around them, if they don't see people as their food but see as the source providing it to them, then why not? Which is of course not to say that they are not drugged in that particular place, but one would need some inside information to verify it.

Comment: Why do you think a tiger can't be trained? Just because it is a predator, doesn't mean it can't be relaxed around humans. Sure, if the tiger goes unfed or a human provokes it in some direct way there could be problems, but it seems plausible to me that the tigers would not be drugged.

Comment: The claim that they are drugged is certainly [notable](https://www.google.com/search?q=tigers%20drugged). That is, it isn't enough to challenge the OP for believing it - we need evidence to convince the hordes either way.

Comment: The image in the question is broken.